# How to get width and height of a Webview in android

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to determine the width and the height of the `WebView`. I have already tried it using:

```
webView.getWidth();
webView.getHeight();
```

but the resulting log always shows them to be 0.

Comment: Can you post your code? Remember you cannot get the width and height of a view in the OnCreate method because the layout hasn't occurred yet.

Comment: i put my code is here   height=mainWebView.getHeight();
       System.err.println("Display Total Height-->"+ mainWebView.getHeight());
       System.err.println("Measure Height-->"+mainWebView.getMeasuredHeight());

Answer (score 6):

Here's a more elegant solution

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        webView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right,int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                 int w= webView.getWidth();
                 int h= webView.getHeight();


            }
        });



    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You were probably checking for the sizes too soon, most likely in the `onCreate`. Instead, try this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(webView, url);
                Log.i(TAG, findViewById(R.id.my_component).getWidth(););
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

The `onPageFinished` call back approach does not work when using `loadData` or `loadDataWithBaseURL`. I saw another solution on [Andromedev](http://android.pimmos.com/2011/03/24/how-to-retrieve-the-contentwidth-of-a-webview/) using JavaScript, but I'm not convinced that this is the best path to take.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who still struggles.
Use these methods to get the height and the width of your webview.

```
computeHorizontalScrollRange(); -> for width 
computeVerticalScrollRange(); -> for height
```

Comment: Note that these may return different values to getWidth() and getHeight() as they return the entire scrollable width/height rather than the actual widht/height of the webview on screen.

Comment: Also note that these methods are protected and you might find it difficult to use them from inside your custom layout for example.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm - I looked through the WevView source and I can see that internally they are using View#getWidth and View#getHeight here's one of the `WebView`'s private methods:

```
/*
 * Return the width of the view where the content of WebView should render
 * to.
 */
private int getViewWidth() {
    if (!isVerticalScrollBarEnabled() || mOverlayVerticalScrollbar) {
        return getWidth();
    } else {
        return getWidth() - getVerticalScrollbarWidth();
    }
}
```

As noted in the comments you have to make sure you are measuring it after you assign the activity layout e.g. `setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);`

Answer (score 1):

you are checking size of webview too early.
you can try this in following method

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
            webView.getWidth();
            webView.getHeight();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the width and height of the WebView CONTENTS, after you loaded your HTML.
YES you do, but there is no getContentWidth method (only a view port value),
AND the getContentHeight() is inaccurate !

Answer: sub-class WebView:

```
/*
  Jon Goodwin
*/
package com.example.html2pdf;//your package

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.webkit.WebView;

class CustomWebView extends WebView
{
    public int rawContentWidth   = 0;                         //unneeded
    public int rawContentHeight  = 0;                         //unneeded
    Context    mContext          = null;                      //unneeded

    public CustomWebView(Context context)                     //unused constructor
    {
        super(context);
        mContext = this.getContext();
    }   

    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) //inflate constructor
    {
        super(context,attrs);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public int getContentWidth()
    {
        int ret = super.computeHorizontalScrollRange();//working after load of page
        rawContentWidth = ret;
        return ret;
    }

    public int getContentHeight()
    {
        int ret = super.computeVerticalScrollRange(); //working after load of page
        rawContentHeight = ret;
        return ret;
    }
//=========
}//class
//=========
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a work-around , instead of fetching from unreliable webview get from DisplayMetrics, assuming you have webview width almost equal to phone screen size and height almost equal to height of phone screensize.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = (int) displayMetrics.heightPixels*0.9;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get The Height and Width load time you can't get it because load time can't get it. I suggest to use the webview Touchevent and get the height and width. Otherwise use another view click event and get the height and width.

```
webView.getWidth();
webView.getHeight();
```

Use this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I just put **initWebView** method in **onWindowFocusChangedt**.

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    initWebView();
}


private void initWebView(){
    if(isOnline()){
        venueWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.venueWebView);
        String url = "some url";
        int viewWight = venueWebView.getWidth();
        int viewHeight = venueWebView.getHeight();
        venueWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope my answer helps somebody.

If you want to get height of `webview` after content is loaded then this could be helpful.

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver  = mWebView.getViewTreeObserver();
viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {
 @Override
 public boolean onPreDraw() {                                
     int height = mWebView.getMeasuredHeight();
        if( height != 0 ){
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"height:"+height,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             mWebView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                       }
                       return false;
               }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the original height after loading content, you can use the below code. Though the code is deprecated, yet it works perfectly.

```
webview.setPictureListener(new WebView.PictureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNewPicture(WebView webView, @Nullable Picture picture) {
            int height = webview.getContentHeight();
            int height1 = webview.getMeasuredHeight();
            int height2 = webview.getHeight();
        }
    });
```