# Get WebView height

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to get WebView height knowing it's content and width. Does anyone know how to do it without loading content into WebView? 
 Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this link


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612628/how-to-get-width-and-height-of-a-webview-in-android

Comment: I've just tried. Does't work...

Answer (score 0):

When we get height of content from webview. we should take care of content height with scale factor. This is how I get solved my problem

Answer (score -1):

**Can you clarify your question: Does anyone know how to do it without loading content into WebView?**

According to the Official Android WebView [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getContentHeight%28%29). getContentHeight() should work.

```
public int getContentHeight()
```

*Since: API Level 1*
Returns the height of the HTML content.

Example:

```
webview.getContentHeight()
```

Comment: This does not work i have a project myself and this method will only return the right values if the content is loaded. Loaded means that the onNewPicture is called for the content. The problem is that this method is deprecated..