# Webview returns zero height and width on PageFinished event

Tags: android, android-webview

Am trying to convert webview to bitmap in android.But the webview height and width is always zero?

Here is the code:

```
String unescaped = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(b
                .getString("issueDescription"));
        try {
            customHtml = new String(unescaped.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        customHtml = "<link rel='Stylesheet' href='index.css'/>" + customHtml;
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.issueDescription);

        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", customHtml, null,
                "utf-8", null);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                 @Override      
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    int mWidth = view.getWidth();
                    int mHeight = view.getHeight();
                    Picture bmp1 = view.capturePicture();
                    PictureDrawable pd1 = new PictureDrawable(bmp1);
                    Bitmap bitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(pd1.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                            pd1.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
                }
            });
```

Comment: did you load url like 
webview.loadUrl("http://slashdot.org/"); ?

Comment: No,am fetching html content from database.

Comment: try out setWebChromeClient' instead of 'setWebViewClient'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the original height after loading content, you can use the below code. Though the code is deprecated, yet it works perfectly.

```
webview.setPictureListener(new WebView.PictureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onNewPicture(WebView webView, @Nullable Picture picture) {
        int height = webview.getContentHeight();
        int height1 = webview.getMeasuredHeight();
        int height2 = webview.getHeight();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to  [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10291069/4207822) `onPageFinished()` call back approach is not working if you use method `loadData()` or `loadDataWithBaseURL`.

It is timing issue that you call `getWidth()` too early before it is fully loaded. My suggestion is to load webview data in advance before you need `getWidth()` data. For example, load webview data `onCreate()` and make it invisible to user don't know about it. You can call `getWidth()` later